# Start debugging in Visual Studio 2010 using different credentials

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to specify the credentials to be used by the app when debugging a desktop app in Visual Studio 2010?  I don't want to change the credentials used to run Visual Studio itself, just those of code being debugged and I want to be able to specify these credentials from Visual Studio.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/eeba26cb-2336-4a80-99f4-ca4167d0758c

Comment: @user1227804 - thanks, that's what I want.  Do you want to put it in an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the answer is the comment from [user1227804](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227804/user1227804), that being this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/eeba26cb-2336-4a80-99f4-ca4167d0758c